# How can I determine if an Okuma lathe has live tooling on the A turret

Tags: okuma

I've looked through all of the spec code tables and can't find any way of detecting if the A turret has an M spindle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for milling spindle on A turret (active tooling), look for NC spec "MULTIPLE MACHINE" / "CCM" `No.3, bit 0.` You can accomplish this using the SCOUT library by doing the following:

```c#
bool MSpindle = Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NC.Bit(Okuma.Scout.Enums.NCSpecGroup.NC1MG, 3, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `GetMSpindleState()` THINC API function in the CMSpindle Class of the Lathe Data API. It will throw a `NotSupportedException` if the *MULTIPLE MACHINE* spec is not active.

To check manually, open the file **OSPMNGCD.CNC** in the C:\OSP-P\ directory of the machine. Scroll down to the NC-SPEC CODE No.1 section and look for the *MULTIPLE MACHINE* spec. Use the following image as a guide to find the spec:

[image]